# finding runtime function involving a while loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, runtime, big-o

I'm trying to find runtime functions and corresponding big-O notations for two different algorithms that both find spans for each element on a stack.  The X passed in is the list that the span is to be computed from and the S passed in is the list for the span.  I think I know how to find most of what goes into the runtime functions and once I know what that is, I have a good understanding of how to get to big-O notation.  What I need to understand is how to figure out the while loops involved.  I think they usually involve logarithms, although I can't see why here because I've been going through with the worst cases being each element is larger than the previous one, so the spans are always getting bigger and I see no connection to logs.  Here is what I have so far:

```
void span1(My_stack<int> X, My_stack<int> &S) { //Algorithm 1
    int j = 0;                                                        //+1
    for(int i = 0; i < X.size(); ++i) { //Find span for each index    //n
        j = 1;                                                           //+1
        while((j <= i) && (X.at(i-j) <= X.at(i))) { //Check if span is larger  //???
            ++j;                                                          //1
        }
        S.at(i) = j;                                                  //+1
    }
}

void span2(My_stack<int> X, My_stack<int> &S) { //Algorithm 2
    My_stack<int> A; //empty stack                                    //+1
    for(int i = 0; i < (X.size()); ++i) { //Find span for each index  //n
        while(!A.empty() && (X.at(A.top()) <= X.at(i))) {               //???
            A.pop();                                                      //1
        }
        if(A.empty())                                                  //+1
            S.at(i) = i+1;
        else
            S.at(i) = i - A.top();
        A.push(i);                                                    //+1
    }
}
```

span1: f(n) = 1+n(1+???+1)

span2: f(n) = 1+n(???+1+1)

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: What happens with the while loops? I used question marks as a placeholder, but what goes in their place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all stack operations are O(1):

- `span1`: Outer loop executes `n` times. Inner loop upto `i` times for each value of `i` from 0 to `n`. Hence total time is proportional to sum of integers from 1 to `n`, i.e. **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**
- `span2`: We need to think about this differently, since the scope of `A` is function-wide. `A` starts as empty, so can only be popped as many times as something is pushed onto it, i.e. the inner `while` loop can only be executed as many times as `A.push` is called, *over the entirety of the function's execution time*. However `A.push` is only called once every outer loop, i.e. `n` times - so the while loop can only execute `n` times. Hence the overall complexity is **O(n)**.